# How to deal with backend dynamically allocated ports on react.js side using axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

This morning I deployed a MERN stack login app in heroku successfully. But, when I tried to login

> GET http://localhost:5000/user/login/email/password net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
>   in the console.

I understood that that the error is because I am making get request in axios using

```
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/user/login/" + this.state.email + "/" + this.state.password).then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.setState({ status: res.status, name: res.data.name });
                    console.log(res.data);
                }
                else
                    throw new Error(res.status);
            }).catch((err) => {
                this.setState({ isInvalid: true });
            })
```

But, the port is being dynamically allocated on the server side.

```
    const port = process.env.PORT||5000;

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server started on port:" + port);
    });
```

Tried allocating only hardcoded value to the port. Still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in your code. You have deployed your app but your URL is still localhost which is not Heroku URL. First of all you need to setup `env` variables for your application like this.

You can put this in some constant file from where you get your end point. Don't write *END POINTS* directly in the ajax calls. Use constant and create a single file for from where you do all the ajax calls of the application.

You can set the `env` for both frontend and backend and this is how you should work. The development env should be separate from production one.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  API = "http://localhost:8000";
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  API = "https://be-prepared-app-bk.herokuapp.com";
}
```

Don't use `GET` for the login and sending email and password in parameters. You should use `POST` and send all the data in body.

Here's how you single ajax file should look alike:

```
import { API_HOST } from "./constants";
import * as auth from "../services/Session";

const GlobalAPISvc = (endPoint, method, data) => {
  const token = auth.getItem("token");
  const uuid = auth.getItem("uuid");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`${API_HOST}${endPoint}`, {
      method: method,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-authentication": token,
        uuid: uuid
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        resolve(json);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  }).catch(error => {
    return error;
  });
};

export default GlobalAPISvc;
```

I have created an application in MERN which I made public on GitHub. Feel free to take help from that. [Repository Link](https://github.com/abdulhaqshah/be-prepared-app-fe)

Comment: Hello. Thank You so much for response. Will edit the code and see if it's working

Comment: Your welcome, let us know if the problem persist. If its work do not forget to mark this up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest you, not to use get request method for login.
Secondly, if you've deployed your backend code then use dynamic url provided by heroku for login request.
e.g. if your url is xyz.heroku.com then `axios.get('xyz.heroku.com/user/login/'+email+'/'+password);`
as now you don't need to hard-code the port or use localhost.

Comment: Hello. Thank You so much for response. Will edit the code and see if it's working